# Pandas: slicing a dataframe into multiple sheets of the same spreadsheet

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe, slice

Say I have 3 dictionaries of the same length, which I combine into a unique `pandas` dataframe. Then I dump said dataframe into an Excel file. Example:

```
import pandas as pd
from itertools import izip_longest

d1={'a':1,'b':2,'c':3,'d':4,'e':5,'f':6}
d2={'a':1,'b':2,'c':3,'d':4,'e':5,'f':6}
d3={'a':1,'b':2,'c':3,'d':4,'e':5,'f':6}

dict_list=[d1,d2,d3]

stats_matrix=[ tuple('dict{}'.format(i+1) for i in range(len(dict_list))) ] + list( izip_longest(*([ v for k,v in sorted(d.items())] for d in dict_list)) )
stats_matrix.pop(0)

mydf=pd.DataFrame(stats_matrix,index=None)

mydf.columns = ['d1','d2','d3']

writer = pd.ExcelWriter('myfile.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')
mydf.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='sole')   
writer.save()
```

This code produces an Excel file with a *unique* sheet:

```
>Sheet1<

d1   d2   d3 
1    1    1
2    2    2
3    3    3
4    4    4
5    5    5
6    6    6
```

**My question:** how can I slice this dataframe in such a way that the resulting Excel file has, say, 3 sheets, in which the headers are repeated and there are two rows of values in each sheet?

**EDIT**

In the example given here the dicts have 6 elements each. In my real case they have 25000, the index of the dataframe starting from `1`. So I want to slice this dataframe into 25 different sub-slices, each of which is dumped into a dedicated Excel sheet of the same main file.

Intended result: *one* Excel file with *multiple* sheets. Headers are repeated.

```
>Sheet1<           >Sheet2<           >Sheet3<

d1   d2   d3       d1   d2   d3       d1   d2   d3 
1    1    1        3    3    3        5    5    5
2    2    2        4    4    4        6    6    6
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First prep your dataframe for writing like this:

```
prepdf = mydf.groupby(mydf.index // 2).apply(lambda df: df.reset_index(drop=True))
prepdf
```

[image]

You can use this function to reset you index instead.

```
def multiindex_me(df, how_many_groups=3, group_names=None):
    m = np.arange(len(df))
    reset = lambda df: df.reset_index(drop=True)
    new_df = df.groupby(m % how_many_groups).apply(reset)
    if group_names is not None:
        new_df.index.set_levels(group_names, level=0, inplace=True)
    return new_df
```

Use it like this:

```
new_df = multiindex_me(mydf)
```

Or:

```
new_df = multiindex_me(mydf,
                       how_many_groups=4,
                       group_names=['One', 'Two', 'Three', 'Four'])
```

Then write each cross section to a different sheet like this:

```
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('myfile.xlsx')
for sheet in prepdf.index.levels[0]:
    sheet_name = 'super_{}'.format(sheet)
    prepdf.xs(sheet).to_excel(writer, sheet_name)
writer.save()
```

Comment: What does `sheet_name = 'super_{}'.format(sheet)` do? Yes, it names the sheets, but how?

Comment: Also, since `mydf.index` starts from `1`, how do you make it start from `0`?

Comment: @CF84 that is string formatting.  I made up `'supe_'` and could be anything you choose.  the `{}` in there goes with the `.format(sheet)` where the value in `sheet` gets placed where the `{}` was in the string.  So you'll iterate over the values `[0, 1, 2]` and `'super_{}'.format(sheet)` will evaluate to `'super_0'`, `'super_1'`, and `'super_2'`.  Replace it as you see fit.

Comment: Say I already have a string variable to use as sheet name. Do I still need to use the `{}.format(sheet)` part? Can't I just assign `sheet_name=myvar`?

Comment: @CF84 I got rid of your index and essentially created one from scratch.  I wanted a `pd.MultiIndex` so I can iterate over that first level.  I find that a useful approach.  It doesn't matter how you do this so long as you separate it the way that is useful to you.

Comment: @CF84 Nope, you can use whatever you'd like as the sheet name.  By all means, play around with this.  Experiment and learn.

Comment: So to recap: the `.apply(lambda df: df.reset_index(drop=True))` resets the index so that it starts from 0, correct? So essentially, I could use any integer in place of `2`, so to create larger slices. True that?

Comment: @CF84 Double True.

Comment: Well, I tried with 1000-element dicts. I did `prepdf = mydf.groupby(mydf.index // 1000).apply(lambda df: df.reset_index(drop=True))` and then `prepdf.index.levels[0]` to see what the levels were. I expected 0, for I only had 1000 elements and the index had been reset. But I got: `Int64Index([0, 1], dtype='int64')`, meaning that there are two slices: one has 999 elements and the other has the 1000th element. So I am missing the last element...

Comment: Ah! the `mydf` I have from running the code you provided had an index that starts with zero.  Your length 1000 experiment went from 1-1000.  had it gone from 0-999 it would have had the expected outcome.  You'll have to subtract one from the numerator if you need to.

Comment: Sorry I got lost. Where to perform the subtraction? Which numerator? Uhmmm... I could use `1001`, couldn't I?

Comment: This is all about creating a MultiIndex specific to what you want the break up to look like.  Update you question to be more specific about what you like to see and we'll figure it out that way.  It's difficult chatting within comments.